# Unity WaitForSeconds function not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement it so that you can shoot 2 times per second. I am doing this by shooting, and then delaying the gun controlling script for 0.5 seconds, but it's not working. I am trying to use the WaitForSeconds function.

I expect that when I click, a shoot immediately happens, and for the next 0.5 seconds clicking will have no effect while the rest of the game happens normally, and after that time, clicking once will shoot again, causing another delay and so on.

Instead, I can shoot over and over with nothing slowing it down.

Here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public string gunType;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            switch (gunType)
            {
                case "pistol":
                    StartCoroutine(ShootThenDelay(0.5f));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    IEnumerator ShootThenDelay(float seconds)
    {
        Shoot();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);

    }
}
```

Comment: "but it's not working" is not a useful problem description. What exactly do you expect and what exactly is happening? Are you starting more than one coroutine? I don't see anything in your script that would prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Coroutine does not delay the method that is starting it (with one exception - see below) .. otherwise your entire app would be frozen.

You could though simply add a flag like e.g.

```
bool canShoot = true;

IEnumerator ShootThenDelay(float seconds)
{
    canShoot = false;
    Shoot();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    canShoot = true;
}
```

and then check for

```
if (canShoot && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
```

---

Alternatively in your case you actually could directly wait until the routine is finished using

```
// Yes! If you make Start return IEnumerator then Unity 
// automatically runs it as a Coroutine
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Looks dangerous but is totally fine for a Coroutine as long as you yield inside
    while(true)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            switch (gunType)
            {
                case "pistol":
                    // "Runs" the shoot routine and waits until it finished
                    // This way a yield at the end actually has an effect
                    yield return ShootThenDelay(0.5f));
                    break;

                default:
                    // Note: This is very important! Make sure all paths within the while yield at least for one frame!
                    yield return null;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Note: This is very important! Make sure all paths within the while yield at least for one frame!
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator ShootThenDelay(float seconds)
{
    Shoot();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because after waiting for 0.5 seconds, the coroutine returns to the point in code where execution was halted, in your example it returns to the line that goes after:
`yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);`
However, there is nothing, so nothing happens. If you do something like this:

```
IEnumerator ShootThenDelay(float seconds)
{
    Shoot();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    Shoot();
}
```

bullet must be shot twice with the delay of 0.5 seconds.
I do recommend you checking the documentation next time :)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html